# find() vs. createQuery

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following script in symfonyproject.

```
use Rowoco\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Place;
.
.

public function getPlacelist( $iduser )
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    $placeRepo = $em->getRepository( "RowocoAllgemeinBundle:Place" );
    $placeEntity = $placeRepo->findBy(
        array(),
        array(),
        $request->request->get( "limitCount" ),
        $request->request->get( "limitStart" )
    );
    //return $placeEntity;

    $q = $em
        ->createQuery("SELECT p.description
                           FROM RowocoAllgemeinBundle:Place p
                           ");
    return $q->getResult();

}
```

I have no special repository or else. But when i use findby(), then i dont get a result. When use createQuery, I got 2 rows as result.

Can you tell me, where i can find the error in my code?

Comment: In your code , there is no condition in findBy(), any if u want to fetch all the results then use findAll() instead of findBy().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findBy` expects an array of key/values, like this one:

```
array(
    'id' => 5,
    'name' => 'john',
    'friends' => array(1,23)
);
```

As you can see in the last entry, you can also pass an array, which has the effed of a `WHERE … IN()` query. What you cannot (AFAIK) pass to `findBy` are ranges and complex patterns.

Comment: can i use ->find( $limitCount, $limitStart, ORDER). I need all rows, ordered by one row

Comment: `find` and `findBy` are completely different, `find` is kind of a super-shortcut to retrieve exactly one entity object.

Comment: Hint: Although you're working with Symfony, you should use the Doctrine documentation to research stuff related to the ORM. For example, the findBy stuff is explained here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

Comment: OK i see, the one i need is ->findAll(), but when i want the result be ordery by a column, then i have to write my own repository.

Comment: You don't have to write a repository method, if you use it only in one place – simply write a query with the query builder. However, if the result set generated by the repository method is needed in several places, then indeed it makes sense to wrap the query into a dedicated method.